# Some troubles with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've just started working with XCode 5.1 and iOS 7.1. 
Im having some problems with PartialViews containing a scrollview. I have this [image: screen](![http://imgur.com/n5KHXgF]). I marked in red the space the scrollview should occupy but its taking more space vertically and horizontally. The viewcontroller and view are defined in the storyboard as freeform of 500x500 and the scrollview is defined like:

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, rowHeight*[lstMatches count])];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, rowHeight*[lstMatches count]);
//.....more elements here, added as subviews of scrollview
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

The problem is the next:

1) The scrollview is wider than its container so I can't click over right buttons. I tried changing the width of the viewcontroller and view to 800 (max width is about 750), but i cant click them.

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you're trying to scroll horizontally then observe that you are setting the width of `scroll.contentSize` to `self.view.frame.size.width`.

Comment: also... your `initWithFrame:` is totally wrong. the `frame` should be smaller than your `contentSize` so... `scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];`

Comment: @staticVoidMan no, i had a mistake in the scroll and it was the reason it was taller than it should. The only problem now is the width.

Comment: erm... ok. if it's scrolling vertically for you then it's good. anyways... i've posted an answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height])];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(5000, rowHeight*[lstMatches count]);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

PS: Change the `contentSize.width` of **5000** to something that suits your needs

Comment: yes, its really a combination of widths. I changed background colors of some elements and i could see what elements were shorter than they should.

Comment: indeed it was. the frame width/height of `scrollView` should always be smaller than the width/height of the `contentSize`. that's how a `scrollView` does :)